# how to get path Context without using themedisplay object in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

Can anyone help me how to get path context in liferay without themedisplay object (means in scheduler )

I am using liferay 6.1

Comment: what information you want to have in scheduler?

Comment: Actually I want themeDisplay object to get context==>      themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext();

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, there's no (simple) way of doing that.**

**The reason is that** the `ThemeDisplay` object is tied to the current user and the current page. In the context of a scheduler (i.e., an automatically triggered event made by the system itself), there's no current logged in user (ok, you could use the default user, but...), and there's no displayed page.

**What you can do however is** to make the required data available from somewhere else. You can store it in a custom property, read it from the DB or get it through services and so on. The `PortalUtil.getPortalURL()` function for instance may be your friend.

**Otherwise**, you need the [request object to get the ThemeDisplay](http://liferay-hacks.blogspot.hu/2014/01/get-themedisplay-from-portletrequest-in.html).

Answer (score 2):

path Context using company Id

```
    Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanies().get(0);
    String portalURL = PortalUtil.getPortalURL(company.getVirtualHostname(),PortalUtil.getPortalPort(), false);
    String pathContext = PortalUtil.getPathContext();
```